# Internal & External URL on Same Port using Host Header is possible in SharePoint 2010 Site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have one confusion... I have created one site using SSL on Port 5556. Now it is on Default Zone & working fine on local network using `https://zyspnlb:5556/vip/...`

Now, Team wants to make that available on internet. They are fine to use the site with port. So, instead of extend the site can I update the Host Header on IIS for that site with Live URL ?

I mean in IIS Basic Setting we have port, http/https & host header setting. if I keep 5556 port as it is, https as it is and in blank of host header if I write www.vip.mycompany.com (which is live url) will it work externally using `http://vip.mycompany.com:5556/vip/...`?

also I want to make that work on internal as it is with `https://zyspnlb:5556/vip/`...

Answer (score 1):

if you want site to be https,then you need to use 443 ports always.you need to extend the site for your external application. something like 5556 for internal and 443 for https external facing site.Expose the 443 port over the internet with DNS entry.then your site name would be https://vip.mycompany.com/vip.